# dropdown select .change not firing form.submit

Tags: jquery, forms

I have the following script

```js
< script >
  jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#filterstype').change(function() {
    //  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
    jQuery('#filter-form').unbind().submit(function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Handler for .change() called.");
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/en/real-estate',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html', //expect return data as html from server
        data: jQuery('#filter-form').serialize(),
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          jQuery('#filter-form').html(jQuery(response).find('#filter-form').html()); //select the id and put the response in the html
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log('error(s):' + textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}); < /script>
```

And the coresponding html co de is as follow

```html
<form action="/en/real-estate" method="post" name="filterform" id="filter-form">

  <input type="text" class="span12" name="filter_search" value="" />




  <select id="filterstype" name="filters[type]">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Properties for sale</option>
    <option value="3">Address</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Search</button>

</form>
```

The form is not being submitted if I chande the selection from the dropdown, but if I click the search button on the form, the code runs, but if I change the drop down the submit dont fire.

What iis it that I am doing wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your event handler for the drop-down `change` event is unbinding all events to the form, then binding a `submit` handler to the form.

It seems from your question you want to actually submit the form. To trigger the submit event, you need to use the no-argument form of `jQuery.submit()`. Try adding an additional `.submit()` to the end of the chain or a `jQuery('#filter-form').submit();` line in the `change` handler.

Comment: Yes I need to submit the form but with the jquery.ajax not the normal form submit as if there is no jquery script, I am trying to interupt the normal submit behavior to refresh the form on it self with new fields.
Your advice is not working, it made the form work as entended for the firsh dropdown change, but not for the 2nd or 3rd dropdown change.

Comment: You may want to read up on Events in the jQuery documentation, and be more clear on what precisely you want the code to do.